# libreoffice 4.4 without gui change

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, gui, lts

i install the last libre office version 4.4 in my ubuntu 14.04 LTS but the gui does not change .

`repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases`

[image: capture]

Comment: Have you looked under **Tools** > **Options** and then looking in **View**, **Personalization**, and/or **Appearance**? You might have to enable it manually. I haven't installed that version, but that would be my best guess.

Comment: I try it . not work

Comment: Sorry, I don't know them. You checked under **View**, as well as **Personalization**, and also **Appearance**?

Comment: yes i checked  all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the Human icon theme for libreoffice, so if you want the sifr icon theme which is the default one used on Mac OS X, you will need to install its package (**libreoffice-style-sifr**) and then go into **Tools** > **Options** > **View** and set the icon style to sifr.

If you want the tango icon theme, which is libreoffice's default icon theme on windows and linux, you will need to install **libreoffice-style-tango**.

Comment: Actually '**Tools > Options > View** and set the icon style to sifr' is enough without installing any additional packages